# Mousedown on objects + GUI interface

Tags: javascript, user-interface, three.js, mousedown

The problem is the following : if i add renderer.domElement to my camera attributes the GUI works perfectly but the mousedown actions don't work.

On the contrary, if i remove renderer.domElement the mousedown actions work but the GUI X-scales with my mouse movements after i've hovered it.

Here is the code :

```
function init()
{

// scene
scene = new THREE.Scene();

// camera
var SCREEN_WIDTH = window.innerWidth, SCREEN_HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;
var VIEW_ANGLE = 45, ASPECT = SCREEN_WIDTH / SCREEN_HEIGHT, NEAR = 0.1, FAR = 20000;
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( VIEW_ANGLE, ASPECT, NEAR, FAR);
camera.lookAt(scene.position);  
var distance = 1000; 
camera.position;y = 150;
camera.position.z = 1500;
scene.add(camera);


// renderer
renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );


// controls
controls = new THREE.TrackballControls( camera);
```

How can i fix it, please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
controls = new THREE.TrackballControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
```

Comment: as i said, if i add renderer.domElement to my camera attributes the GUI works perfectly but the mousedown actions don't work.

Comment: Well. Then we can only guess of what it may happen. It would be helpful if you could put together a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) that highlights your issue.

Comment: I am sorry I don't know how to include my whole package of library, so I am giving a link of the .zip containing everything. Sorry for the incovenience : http://www.mediafire.com/download.php?vfclcwci81t7uc5.
Thank you for your time and your patience.

Comment: Your code and `TrackballControls` are both listening to mouse events. Plus you are simultaneously using the third-party THREEx library. You are going to have to work this one out yourself -- it is too much to debug for you.

Comment: It seems that taking out the trackballcontrols line makes the GUI and mouse events work correctly, but I need the camera - mouse rotation. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: Is there a way to use camera trackballcontrols while having at the same time MouseDown actions + a GUI interface?